# count cells based on value if consecutive values same and more than 6 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In Microsoft Excel 2013, I need to count the number of cells in a row that contain the number `8` and are also part of a sequence of at least 6 consecutive cells containing `8` (ignore if the value is other than `8` or in less than 6 consecutive cells).

e.g. like here:
[image: Sample as shown in picture]

I believe this will require a VBA Code, can't imagine a formula to work here.

Comment: I think you need to provide a few more examples with expected results. What should the result be, for example, if the range contains more than one group of 6 or more consecutive values?

Comment: Please insert screenshot / data from your spreadsheet, questions should be self containing, and not referring to external files (not to mention security issues). Also you tagged your qeustion as Excel, but shared a Google spreadsheet, in which tool do you need help (please note that Google spreadsheet is off-topic here, should ask on webapps stackexchange). Please also make sure your description of the question is clear (e.g. include desired output too).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - new user trying to get around how to post correctly. Will try and attached the excel sheet to the original question.

Comment: Do you need also to identify which cells are repeated, or you know already you want to count `8`s?

Comment: Thanks Mate. I don't need to identify if cell values are repeated - just need to count the number of cells if they contain number 8 at least 6 times (or more) in succession.

Comment: Oooh this is a fun little puzzle! I can definitely see this being doable with VBA. You would need to use a couple of FOR and WHILE loops to do it. One loop would need to track your current column and iterate from 1 to 33 to represent the starting position for checking a sequence of 6 cells. Another loop would need to track the number of consecutive cells that are of equal value. You could create a boolean to track this number, called seq_count (true).

Comment: If positions 1-6 are equal, check position 7, if #7 is the same, check #8, and when you find one that's different, change the boolean to false and add the cell count of #1-#(endpoint) to your desired total. Then you would have to make sure your next iteration of the outer (1-33) loop starts at the next column after the end of your last 6 or larger sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array formula**** in `AH2`:

`=SUM(IFERROR(AJ$1+SQRT(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:AG2=AI$1,COLUMN(A2:AG2)),IF(A2:AG2<>AI$1,COLUMN(A2:AG2)))-AJ$1)^2,0))`

where `AI1` contains the search value (e.g. 8) and `AJ1` the minimum consecutive streak (e.g. 6).

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Answer (score -1):

*Write this Array formula in Cell `AH2`finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill down.*

```
{=SUM((B2:AG2=A2:AF2)*(B2:AG2=8))}
```

**Edited:** *Included the Screen Shot on OP's demand*

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rajesh, but this is not working as intended, the count is coming out as 18 and 14 instead of 14 and 6. The solution by XOR above gives the correct count.

Comment: @EdBright,, I've successfully tested the Formula before I've posted the answer,, I'm really surprised that is not working for you !!

Comment: Sorry @Rajesh, I may be it the wrong way. See the screen shot below:

Comment: @EdBright, I've used the same data what has been used by you for the formula !

Comment: could not post the screen shot. Sorry @Rajesh, I may be making a mistake while copying the formula. Not to forget - the purpose here is to count "all the cells" containing number 8 - IF - there are at least 6 or more cells in the string. I am not sure why the formula is returning 18 - because the total number of 8s in the row are 23 and consecutive 8s are 6 and 8 which is 14.

Comment: Sure ,, Soon I'll

Comment: @EdBright,, check I've posted Screen Shot.

Comment: This formula cannot work as the OP desires, since it contains no clause which restricts the count to looking only at cases of 6 or more consecutive 8s. 3 consecutive 8s, for example, would be counted by your construction.

Comment: @XORLX,, look at first row has 20 8 (3+6+7) but formula counts only 13(6+7) !!☺

Comment: @Rajesh S Can you repost your screenshot so that includes the formula bar showing your formula for that row?

Comment: Now nothing  else is required since I've posted sufficient information and earlier this post has got 1 UP vote, means it has worked for other also !! ☺